# Microsoft Graph API Android 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: android, maven, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm currently following Microsoft's tutorial at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-android) to integrate the Graph API into my project. I have gotten as far as adding all of the suggested edits to my app gradle file, as well as creating the `auth_config_single_account.json` file. Replacing the default values with all of the necessary values pertaining to my environment. Whenever I build my project I am given the error: `Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK/com/microsoft/identity/client/msal/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway`

Any ideas what could cause this to happen?

Comment: All the content tags aren't applicable... that's a `maven` issue, no matter how it was produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL is actually `HTTP502`: https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK/com/microsoft/identity/client/msal/maven-metadata.xml

Because `jcenter()` has been shutdown and `mavenCentral()` is the usually the suggested replacement. I'd rather wish for some canonical Q & A, because the same one question keeps popping up over and over again, where only the environment in which it may happen varies.

Comment: Please help educate me. Where exactly is the solution in this answer?

Comment: The solution is to replace a repository URL which doesn't exist anymore, with one that does. Usually one can find two occurrences of `jcenter()` in file/s `build.gradle` (the one is for Gradle plugins and the other one is for Java dependencies).

Comment: https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/